# Program freeware - reminder that blinks a message on a computer screen

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks, daemon

Do you know a freeware program  - reminder that blinks a message on a computer screen
and can be scheduled for a certain time, let's say the hour when you may quit your work
place and go home?

Something like at 6 pm it starts blinking:

" Go home !! "

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: @ChrisF windows xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php). Lite version is freeware and contains the functionality you need.

While the reminder doesn't blink it will pop on top of other windows and you get a sound alarm with it. You can set one time events or recurring events. You can also select what sound you want to play for the reminder.

Comment: Hi could you explain in more detail, because when I looked at rainlendar the shortest duration is 1 day??

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what OS you are running so I'm going to assume it is a Windows variant from 2000 or later. All recent Windows variants have a task scheduler and the "windows scripting host" through which you can run scripts written in vbscript or jscript, so a simple way to do what you are looking for without installing extra software is:

1. create a text file called "alertme.vbs" or some such containing the line `MsgBox "Go home."`
2. find the windows task scheduler interface (it has not always been in the same place so exactly where to find it depends on which Windows version you are using) and ask it to run that script at 1800 each week day

Answer (score 1):

for windows , try Remind Me In  at http://www.khalidpeace.com/downloads.php
I use it all the time. Set it for the time to remind you and it pops up at the bottom of the screen. You can also set it to play a sound file.

Comment: that domain name is no longer active.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Vista or 7, the task scheduler can be set to pop up a message window.  If that's all you need, then you may as well use what's built into the OS.  Simply create a basic task, and select the option to display a message.

Comment: I tried this and Task sceduler wasn't practical for a blink reminder. The window popped up behind other windows, would require ok to be clicked every time and recurrence is too long to be of use when blinking needs to be every 6 secs on average

Answer (score 0):

I also tried outlook recurring appointment, but that didn't work, because again the recurrence is too long to be of use for a blink reminder.